# RSpec - mocking a class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, rspec

I'm trying to mock a class method with rspec:

**lib/db.rb**

```
class Db
  def self.list(options)
    Db::Payload.list(options)
  end
end
```

**lib/db/payload.rb**

```
class Db::Payload
  def self.list(options={})
  end
end
```

In my spec, I'm trying to setup the expectation Db::Payload.list will be called when I call Db.list:

```
require 'db/payload'

describe Db do
  before(:each) do
    @options = {}
    Db::Payload.should_receive(:list).with(@options)
  end

  it 'should build the LIST payload' do
    Db.list(@options)
  end
end
```

The problem is that I am always receiving the following error:

```
undefined method `should_receive' for Db::Payload:Class
```

Any help understanding this error would be most appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you define a config.mock in your Rspec configure ?

Answer (score 13):

Your `spec_helper.rb` should have something like this:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # RSpec uses its own mocking framework by default. If you prefer to
  # use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
end
```

The default argument is `config.mock_with :rspec` which enables the `should_receive` method. If you're using Mocha, for example, the equivalent is `expects`, so make sure you're using the right mocking framework.